# When $\ \lim\limits_{ p \to +\infty } \ A(p) = B$, how can we prove $\ \lim\limits_{ p \to +\infty } \| A(p)\| = \ \| B\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ and $B$ are matrices.

When $\ \lim\limits_{p\to +\infty}\ A(p) = B$, how can we prove that $$\ \lim_{ p \to +\infty }\|  A(p)\| = \ \| B\|$$ while $\Vert A \Vert$ is the squared norm of $A$, $\sqrt{ \text{Tr}[A^*A] }$?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You just need to note that the norm of A is continuous in the entries of A. Continuous functions and limits commute

Comment: What does $ \lim_{p\to +\infty}\ A(p) = B$ mean? Is it convergence in norm?

Comment: @Botond I meant to convergence in a matrix B and A(p) is matrix-valued functions.

Comment: @Botond... If these are $n \times n$ real or complex matrices, then all reasonable notions of convergence agree.  So this is a special case.

Comment: @GEdgar There are no description about the form of the matrices in the quetion.

Comment: Admittedly, the question is deficient.  It does not even mention the word "matrix".

Comment: @GEdgar That is true. Sorry about that.